# Find $dy/dx$ of $r=2+3sin(\theta)$

Tags: calculus

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ of the tangent lines shown on the graph of the polar equation.$r=2+3\sin\theta$.

I know I have to convert to rectangular form so I got

$x^2 + y^2 -3y - 2 = 0$

and the derivative of that is

$2x+2y-3$

But I got the wrong answer.

Comment: You should be more explicit as to what exactly you are differentiating. It's not very clear from the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it

Comment: When you differentiate, you have to do so with respect to a variable. If you differentiate your expression with respect to, say, $x$ then you get $2x + 2y \frac{dy}{dx} - 3 \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us the graph or which point you're supposed to find the tangent slope on.

Answer (score 2):

the polar graph of $r = 2 + 3\sin \theta$ is not a circle as your cartesian equation indicates. the graph is called a cardioid, i believe.  use the transformation $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ to go between polar $[r, \theta]$ and cartesian $(x,y)$

multiplying by $r$ gives $r^2 = 2r + 3y$. square it once more to get $$4(x^2 + y^2) = (x^2+y^2 - 3y)^2$$

differentiate the above implicitly, $$8(xdx + ydy) = 2(x^2+y^2-3y)(2xdx + 2ydy - 3dy).$$

you can go from here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert this to rectangular coordinates. There is a better way to do this.

Since $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, we can treat $x$, $y$ and $r$ as functions of $\theta$ and use the chain rule to find $dy/dx$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = \frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}(r\sin\theta)}{\frac{d}{d\theta}(r\cos\theta)} = \frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta + r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta - r\sin\theta} $$

We have $r = 2 + 3\sin\theta$ and $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = 3\cos\theta$, so

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3\cos\theta\sin\theta + (2+3\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{3\cos^2\theta - (2+3\sin\theta)\sin\theta} = \frac{6\sin\theta\cos\theta + 2\cos\theta}{3(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)-2\sin\theta} = \frac{3\sin 2\theta + 2\cos\theta}{3\cos 2\theta - 2\sin\theta} $$

The actual value of the slope depends of the values of $x$ and $y$, or which point you are looking at.